# Google Protocol Buffers int32 vs int64

Tags: protocol-buffers

If I store an integer field in int32...will this use more space than int64?
From what I understand the varint will adjust its size with the size of the number being stored.

Comment: Can you post your protocol buffer definition where this occurs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this only impacts the generated code. Any combination of `[s|u]int{32|64}` uses "varint" encoding, so the size is generally related to the magnitude, at least after noting the difference in negative numbers. In particular, a negative number that **doesn't** use `sint*` will be disproportionately large (10 bytes, IIRC), regardless of whether it is 32 or 64.